Could not load file or assembly version=1.0.0.0 .wpf project
<Application x:Class="CandyKeeper.Presentation.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CandyKeeper.Presentation"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CandyKeeper.Presentation.ViewModels"
         xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
         StartupUri="Views/Windows/MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources >

    <ResourceDictionary>
        //Стили 

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    
</Application.Resources>

Когда пытаюсь объявить локатор в App.xaml, пишет эту ошибку. Из-за этого не могу объявить локатор в DataContext MainWindow.xaml. Проверял пространства имён и всё совпадает, но он не видит класс.


ПКМ по проекту - очистить, далее пересобрать. Если не помогает, то закрываем студию, открываем папку проекта, удаляем весь "мусор" по типу bin, obj, .vs, .user, запускаем, повторно чистка и пересборка. Если и это не помогло, то в коде ошибка, смотрите все ошибки (у вас их вон 5), для обновления данных XAML нужна успешная сборка проекта!

Очистить и пересобрать не помогло.После очистки папок bin, obj,user — проект перестаёт загружаться. Попробовал удалить его и создать заново, добавляя старые файлы, ошибки вроде исчезли,но XAML все равно не показывает ViewModels. А после очистки решения и опять же пересборки — старые ошибки вновь появляются.

"проект перестаёт загружаться" - не может такого быть, значит не то удаляете (.user) если что - это файл. Смотрите значит лог, почему он не загружается. Ну и повторю "Если и это не помогло, то в коде ошибка, смотрите все ошибки (у вас их вон 5)".

Удалил библиотеку, закомментировал вызовы. Осталась только изначальная ошибка. Я не могу объявить ViewModelLocator, будет could not load file or assembly. Если не объявлять, то она исчезнет, но я даже просто в контексте любой другой VM не могу указать, он считает, что их не существует в объявленном пространстве имён, хотя всё там есть. При сборке он не видит никаких проблем, все 4 - успешно.
